# Post-process GStreamer playbin pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-sharp

The `playbin` pipeline in GStreamer is a wonderful thing in that I don't need to have *any* real knowledge about the individual elements needed to process the stream.

However, if I wanted to rotate the video 90 degrees (or flip it, or anything else), it appears I have to manually code up the pipeline. At the moment, I'm doing this with:

```
rtspsrc location=X
    ! rtph264depay
    ! h264parse
    ! decodebin
    ! videoflip method=Y
    ! videoconvert
    ! autovideosink
```

However, because I'm binding the video to a specific Gtk widget, I capture the message asking for the widget ID and provide that back to GStreamer so it can correctly bind.

Unfortunately, according to `gst-inspect-1.0`, none of those elements in the pipeline above appear to actually provide the `GstVideoOverlay` interface so that, when I query for one that can receive the widget identifier, I get `null` followed very quickly by a null pointer error. Or, if I do nothing when the `null` is returned, no binding occurs and GStreamer opens up a separate window to stream the video.

It turns out that `playbin` itself provides the required interface.

I also tried replacing `autovideosink` with `ximagesink`, and then with `xvimagesink`, both of which claim to support the interface but, in both cases, no element was found that supported the interface.

So my question s are basically this:

1/ Can I insert something into the above pipeline that will provide the interface?

2/ Failing that, is there a way to use `playbin` to analyse the stream correctly but then capture its output and pass that through more filters? The sort of thing I'm thinking of is:

```
playbin location=X
    ! videoflip method=Y
    ! autovideosink
```

In other words, can I use something like the `video-sink` property of `playbin` to stop it creating its own sink and instead pass its data through to the `videoflip`?

I'd prefer something that could be implemented with `Gst.Parse.Launch()` since I don't really want to have to mess about creating every single pipeline element manually if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the way you are requesting the GstVideoOverlay is not correct or there is a bug in GStreamer, xvimagesink and ximagesink both support GstVideoOverlay interface. autovideosink doesn't but it is likely that the videosink inside it will support.

Anyway, you want to have a custom bin set to the video-sink property. You can create your bin and put the elements you want inside it, create a sink ghostpad and then set it as the video-sink of your playbin.

It is also possible to do it using parse-launch syntax:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin video-sink="videoconvert ! videoscale ! aasink" uri=file://<path/to/some/file>
```

Just replace the bin elements with whatever you need.